# A question on a sequence of open covering

Tags: general-topology

We say that $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal if there exists a sequence $\{\mathcal U_n: n\in \omega\}$ of open covering of $X$ such that for each $x\in X$, $\{x\} =\bigcap St(x,\mathcal U_n)$, where $St(x,\mathcal U_n)=\{U\in \mathcal U_n: x\in U_n\}.$

If we make the sequence $\{\mathcal U_n: n\in \omega\}$ of open covering of $X$ satisfy that $\mathcal U_{n+1}$ refines $\mathcal U_{n}$ for every $n \in \omega$. Then

1) Could the new sequence of open covering of $X$ still witness that $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal?

2) Let $\mathcal B=\bigcup \{U\in \mathcal U_n: n\in \omega\}$. Note here is the new sequence of open covering of $X$. Is $\mathcal B$ a base of $X$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes, it does. Let $\mathscr{V}_0=\mathscr{U}_0$. Given $\mathscr{V}_n$, let $$\mathscr{V}_{n+1}=\{U\cap V:U\in\mathscr{U}_{n+1}\text{ and }V\in\mathscr{V}_n\text{ and }U\cap V\ne\varnothing\}\;.$$ Then $\mathscr{V}_{n+1}$ refines $\mathscr{V}_n$ and $\mathscr{V}_n$ refines $\mathscr{U}_n$ for each $n\in\omega$. For any $x\in X$ and $n\in\omega$ we have $\operatorname{St}(x,\mathscr{V}_n)\subseteq\operatorname{St}(x,\mathscr{U}_n)$, so $\{\mathscr{V}_n:n\in\omega\}$ still witnesses the fact that $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal.

(2) No, $\mathscr{B}$ is not necessarily a base for $X$. Let $p\in\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, and let $X$ be the subspace $\{p\}\cup\omega$ of $\beta\omega$. $X$ is a countable Hausdorff space, so it certainly has a $G_\delta$-diagonal. For $n\in\omega$ let

$$\mathscr{U}_n=\big\{\{k\}:k<n\big\}\cup\big\{\{p\}\cup\{k\in\omega:k\ge n\}\big\}\;;$$

then $\mathscr{U}_n$ is an open cover of $X$, $\mathscr{U}_{n+1}$ refines $\mathscr{U}$ for each $n\in\omega$, and the family and $\{\mathscr{U}_n:n\in\omega\}$ witnesses the fact that $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal. However, the corresponding $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, while $X$ is not first countable at $p$, so $\mathscr{B}$ is not a base for $X$.

Comment: Does such $X$ have countable pseudocharacter?

Comment: @Paul: Every countable $T_1$-space has countable pseudocharacter: if $X$ is such a space, and $x\in X$, then $$\{x\}=\bigcap_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}(X\setminus\{y\})\;.$$

Comment: Thanks Brain. I still want to know: for any open set $U \subseteq X$ ($X$ is orginal space), then does there exist some element $B$ of $\mathcal B$ such that $B \subseteq U$?

Comment: @Paul: So you’re really asking whether $\mathscr{B}$ will always be a $\pi$-base for $X$?

Comment: O it is. I'm not familar with $\pi$-base. when you mentioned, I rember.